# Spring Async ThreadPoolTaskScheduler not initialized

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I'm trying to use Async annotation in Spring but I'm getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ThreadPoolTaskScheduler not initialized
```

error, when I try to run the method marked as Async. The following is the configuration for Async:

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@Configuration 
public class SchedulingConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer{

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(10);
        return scheduler;
    }

}
```

and the following is the declaration of async method.

```
@Async
@Transactional(value = "baseTransactionManager", isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public void foo(Bar bar) {// some code here}
```

What am I missing in here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You have to explicitly call `scheduler.initialize()` after setting all properties but before returning the scheduler.

See full working test case [here](https://gist.github.com/yarosla/e1cfe46087a93c2fa3b0d8ec49595dd3).

Comment: Thanks, the exception does not occur but the method with async does not perform either. Are there anything else that I should do?

Comment: @small_ticket What exactly do you mean by 'does not perform'? The `foo()` method - is it inside properly configured Spring bean, eg. `FooService`? Do you call it from other bean where `FooService` is autowired, or from the same bean?

Comment: foo is in a Service FooService and I'm calling it from another Service CallerService where FooService is autowired. The code in the foo does not execute, this is what i mean. It doesn't print the logs, it doesn't insert the necessary data into the database, etc.

Comment: @small_ticket Try making this `foo()` really simple. Without `Transactional`, with single logging line inside.

Comment: Stavnichy I found the reason why my async method is not working. I have to specify componentScan in my Configuration class. My configuration class is imported in the main configuration and I have the component scan in my parent configuration file. However, it is not enough for Async, therefore I've added componentScan to the AyncConfiguration file and everything works just fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that calling `initialize()` is necessary only if your scheduler is not a Spring bean, otherwise it is called automatically in `afterPropertiesSet()`.